# ISingleResult does not contain a definition for 'Single' and no extension method 'Single'

Tags: linq-to-sql

i am getting a weird error. my sproc looks like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveFaq] (  @Id int , @Question nvarchar(MAX) , @Answer nvarchar(MAX) , @Status nvarchar(50) , @ModifiedBy nvarchar(50)  )
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON ; 
    Declare @newId as INT  
    if not exists(select * from [Faq]  where [Id] = @Id)
    begin 
        INSERT into [Faq] (  [Question], [Answer], [Status], [ModifiedBy], [CreatedDate] ,  [CreatedBy] ,  [ModifiedDate] )  VALUES (   @Question, @Answer, @Status, @ModifiedBy, GETDATE() , @ModifiedBy ,  GETDATE() )
        select @newId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    end
    else begin  
        UPDATE [Faq] SET   [Question] = @Question, [Answer] = @Answer, [Status] = @Status, [ModifiedBy] = @ModifiedBy,  [ModifiedDate] = GETDATE()
        Where Id = @Id
        select @newId = @Id
    end   
    Select * from  [Faq] where Id = @newId
```

notice the last like will select the newly inserted record

```
public static int Save(int id, string question, string answer, WorkflowStatus status, string modifiedBy)
    {
        using (var dc = ProjectLogic.GetDataContext())
        {
            return dc.SaveFaq(id, question, answer, status.ToString(), modifiedBy).Single().Id; 
        }
    }
```

i get an error like this..

```
'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<Web.Data.DataContext.SaveFaqResult>' does not contain a definition for 'Single' and no extension method 'Single' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<Web.Data.DataContext.SaveFaqResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: I will be cleaning this up soon

Comment: What is the return type of SaveFaq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed wrong namespace.

One namespace is regular Linq, the other one is Linq2sql.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045.aspx

Answer (score 0):

apperently i'm using the wrong namespace

use this

```
using System.Linq;
```

NOT this

```
using System.Data.Linq;
```

I have no idea why...

Comment: ISingleResult derives from IEnumerable not IQueryable, thus you need the LINQ to Objects extensions to extend and further refine your results. This is intentional because stored procs can't be extended with further querying on the server side the same way that tables and views can.